# Cell contents not visible on formula bar

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

My excel version 16.15 shows cell address in the formula bar. It does not show cell content or formulas. I have turned the formula bar on and off and checked preferences for hints, but I can't figure it out. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Some screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: If you select a cell with data, but the formula bar shows the cell address, and you start typing in that cell, does the correct data you enter show up in the formula bar? Or is it still "blank"?  Or, select a cell with contents where the formula bar shows the address, and press `F2`. Does the formula bar correct itself then? 
 A screenshot would help.

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about the formula bar and not the name box?

Answer (score 1):

If you format cells.
The Hidden checkbox will mean that when a sheet is protected, the formulas will not be visible.
You can un-protect the sheet, remove the Hidden check, or both, depending on how you use the sheet.

[image]